# How to Sort by Column

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix

In Matlab, how would I sort the 6th column where the 6th column represents a top score:

```
8   5   2   9   5   0
4   6   4   9   3   1
5   2   3   1   8   1
8   3   2   1   6   10
```

To form an output of:

```
8   3   2   1   6   10
5   2   3   1   8   1
4   6   4   9   3   1
8   5   2   9   5   0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your matrix is called A,

```
B = sortrows(A, -6)
```

Should do a descending order sort based on the 6th column.

See [this matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html) for more information.